# CocoPod SideMenu not working when clicking menu

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, side-menu

I have a View Controller with a CollectionView with images in it.

When I try adding a [SideMenu](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SideMenu) to it with a TableView I get the following error when tapping the bar button `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'must pass a class of kind UITableViewCell'`

I am using this tutorial to implement [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iq-tWW45Vhk&t=668s)

Any reason for this error? What should I change?

Here is my ViewController Class

```
import SideMenu
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var menu: SideMenuNavigationController?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var imgArr = ["1","2","3"]
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        menu = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: MenuListController())
        menu?.leftSide = true
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = menu
        SideMenuManager.default.addPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.view)
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapMenu(){
        present(menu!, animated: true)
    }

}


extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgArr.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCollectionViewCell
        cell?.img.image = UIImage(named:imgArr[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }
    
}

class MenuListController:UITableViewController{
    
    var items = ["First", "Second"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellmenu")
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellmenu", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` of `MenuListController`, you have to register `UITableViewCell` not `UITableView`, add `tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellmenu")` that's why you getting the error

Comment: Genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register `UITableViewCell` not `UITableView`, that's why you getting the error

In `viewDidLoad()` of `MenuListController`,

add

`tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellmenu")`

instead of

`tableView.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellmenu")`